# Ho do I add/require a full php file into a variable in a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, require

I'm building in Wordpress and have some content that loads in using jQuery.load.

```
$item = '<h2>'. the_title() .'</h2><div>'. the_content() .'</div>';
//$item = include 'myrequire.php'; This doesn't seem to work.
```

I'd like to know how to make the php variable $item load a php file - so I can keep functions.php tidy and can just write the file like:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?><h2>
```

... does that make sense?

Thanks!

I followed this tutorial:
http://tomsbigbox.com/wordpress-load-more-posts-on-page-scroll/

here's the full snippet:

```
function getArchives($count,$offset){
query_posts('posts_per_page='.$count.'&offset='.$offset);

$posts = array();

if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();    


    $item = '<h2>'. the_title() .'</h2><div>'. the_content() .'</div>';
    //$item = include 'myrequire.php';

array_push($posts,$item); endwhile; endif;

return $posts;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You want to know the content of a php file?

Answer (score 0):

include executes the file, you want file_get_contents

```
$var=file_get_contents($filename);
```

youcan also do it the wordpress way with get_template_part but that depends on what you want to do. I would look at the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should be right but unfortunately my code fails to load the file in. there's something else going on ( it seems to ignore the html tags in my working example up there.. and if i grab the external file it loads <nothing> :/ )

Comment: maybe it is path issue. in that case, try the absolute path to the file. alternatively it may be a permission issue and in that case try to chmod 777 that file